# More than one virtual host does not work as expected

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I want to serve more than one host name on a server on a specific port. Let's say namely;

example1.com, example2.com, example3.com, example4.com.

I have configured them as;

```
<VirtualHost example1.com:85>
    ServerName www.example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com example1.com
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost example2.com:85>
    ServerName www.example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com example2.com
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost example3.com:85>
    ServerName www.example3.com
    ServerAlias www.example3.com example3.com
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost example4.com:85>
    ServerName www.example4.com
    ServerAlias www.example4.com example4.com
    .
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

When I use this configuration, it recommands me to use NameVirtualHost and all sites goes to first one.

When I add NameVirtulHost to each one it says www.example2.com, www.example3.com and www.example4.com has no virtualhosts. And first one goes to correct one but the others goes to second one.

How can I do this configuration properly.

Comment: You only need one `NameVirutalHost` - `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your main config should do the trick

Comment: Can you be more spesific please? What exactly should I do? I am really very beginner about this issue :)

Comment: You said: `When I add NameVirtulHost to each one` I said: `You only need one NameVirutalHost` I can't be much clearer! Look at the [example here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you only need each virtualhost to have the argument *:80, one NameVirtualHost *:80, then ServerAlias/ServerName in each VirtualHost. Using a hostname in virtualhost causes all sorts of trouble.